# Selectize with bootstrap3 input-group-addon height

Tags: selectize.js

I'm new to HTML, Javascript, bootstrap, selectize. Height of glyphicon is not being rendered properly.
Where am I wrong, please help.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>My Shop!</title>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.4/css/selectize.bootstrap3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.4/js/standalone/selectize.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
   <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
     <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
    </span>
    <select class="form-control" id="txnParty">
     <option>one</option>
     <option>two</option>
    </select>
   </div>
  <script>
  $('select').selectize();
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this way:

```
$('#select').selectize({
    inputClass: 'form-control selectize-input', 
    dropdownParent: "body"
});
```

see: https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/issues/600